Misunderstanding of chain rule given partial derivative of multivariable function
I am currently preparing a Mechanics exam, and calculus has never been my forte. While studying Hamilton's equations, I encountered the following problem, which is no doubt related to my lack of proficiency with the aforementioned subject:
Let $f$ be a real function of $m$ variables $g_1$, $g_2$, $...$ , $g_m$, and let these variables be functions themselves, of $n$ variables $x_1$, $x_2$, $...$, $x_n$.
The chain rule states that
$$\frac{df}{dx_i}=\sum_{j=1}^{m} \frac{\partial f}{\partial g_j} \frac{dg_j}{dx_i} \quad \forall i \in {1,...,n}\ . $$
I have found several sources, including the wikipedia page on the chain rule ("Multivariable case" section, "General rule", case $k=1$), stating that an equivalent statement holds for partial derivatives:
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}= \sum_{j=1}^{m} \frac{\partial f}{\partial g_j} \frac{\partial g_j}{\partial x_i} \quad \forall i \in {1,...,n }$$
Now let's say $m=2$, so $f$ is a function of two variables $g_1(x_1,...,x_n)$ and $g_2(x_1,...,x_n)$, and let's define $g_1(x_1,...,x_n) = x_1$. $\ $Consider
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}= \frac{\partial f}{\partial g_1} \frac{\partial g_1}{\partial x_1} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial g_2} \frac{\partial g_2}{\partial x_1}.$$
Given $\ g_1(x_1,...,x_n)=x_1,\ $ we have
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1} \frac{\partial x_1}{\partial x_1}+ \frac{\partial f}{\partial g_2} \frac{\partial g_2}{\partial x_1} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial g_2} \frac{\partial g_2}{\partial x_1},$$
which would imply
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial g_2} \frac{\partial g_2}{\partial x_1}=0,$$
even though I only made assumptions about $g_1$, therefore for general $f$ and $g_2$ this value shouldn't have any reason to vanish.
Where does the problem lie? Does it have to do with the fact that in my example $g_2$ is effectively a function of $g_1$?

"The chain rule states that ... an equivalent statement holds for partial derivatives" What is the definition of $\frac{df}{dx_i}$?

When you write $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}\frac{\partial x_1}{\partial x_1}+\dots,,$$ the symbol $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}$ appears once on the left hand side and once on the right hand side, and they have different meanings. (This shows that we do not necessarily have $\frac{\partial f}{\partial g_2}\frac{\partial g_2}{\partial x_1}=0$)

@Andrew That is probably exactly where my problem is, I thought those would signify the same thing, hence why I thought they would cancel out. How are their meanings different? If it's too long to explain, could you point me towards some material I can read through myself?

The symbol on the left hand side means the first partial of the function $ f\circ g$. The symbol on the right hand side means the first partial of the function $f$ evaluated at the point $g(x)$. It is helpful to look at the chain rule and compare: If $h = f\circ g$, then $h'(x) = f'(g(x))g'(x)$. You can find some more explanation in chapter 2 of Spivak's Calculus on Manifolds.

@Andrew Thank you so much, I knew I was missing something very basic. That's exactly the answer I needed, is there some way I can mark it as such, even though it's a comment? Otherwise thanks again and have a good one
